# Creating subdomain aliases

Tags: linux, centos, subdomain, plesk

I have a server with Plesk 10.4 on CentOS6, which has an interface for creating aliases of a domain, but not aliases of a subdomain.

For example I have this subdomain set up:

```
test.my-domain.co.uk
```

And then I want to create aliases so that the following subdomains map to the same root:

```
alias-1.my-domain.co.uk 
alias-2.my-domain.co.uk
alias-3.my-domain.co.uk
```

I've tried creating a vhost.conf file like this:

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/my-domain.co.uk/subdomains/test>
    # aliases
    ServerAlias alias-1.my-domain.co.uk
    ServerAlias alias-2.my-domain.co.uk
    ServerAlias alias-3.my-domain.co.uk
</Directory>
```

And then reconfiguring all domains:

```
/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/httpdmng --reconfigure-all
```

However that fails.

Is this possible? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to

- copy files and related data of subdomain to somewhere
- delete subdomain
- create add-on domain test.my-domain.co.uk

Now you should have ability to create aliases for test.my-domain.co.uk.

**[update]**

You are able create subdomain test.my-domain.co.uk and add-on domain test.my-domain.co.uk.
The difference in fact that for add-on domain you will have ability to create domain aliases.

Comment: How would this help? That's no different to what I've done already which is to create a subdomain called test.mydomain.co.uk. This version of Plesk doesn't provide a way to add aliases of subdomains so when you say '...you should have the ability...', how exactly?

Comment: The difference in that there is no way to create domain alias for _subdomain_, but for add-on domain test.my-domain.co.uk it will be possible.

Comment: Sorry - what's an add-on domain?

Comment: OK I follow now. Plesk doesn't have anything termed 'add-on' domain but I just created new domains called alias-1.my-domain.co.uk, alias-2.my-domain.co.uk etc and pointed them to the webroot of test.my-domain.co.uk and that achieved what I was looking for. Thanks